# Elastalert2 WARNING:apscheduler.scheduler skipped: maximum number of running instances reached

Tags: linux, logging, elastic-stack, elk, elastalert2

I am trying to run elastalert2 on my Centos 8 machine, and I get this error while doing so

> WARNING:apscheduler.scheduler:Execution of job "Rule: Testing Email Alert (trigger: interval[0:00:05], next run at: 2023-07-10 15:31:11 IST)" skipped: maximum number of running instances reached (1)

It used to run without this type of issues some days ago but now it gives me this error.

I used this command to run elastalert

```
python -m elastalert.elastalert --verbose --rule rules/example_frequency.yaml
```

I thought of this as a casual warning and tried to test elastalert but I did not receive any email alert for the Frequency rule

Usually this error would occur as soon as I run this command, but sometimes my elastalert2 starts running as it should but as soon as I create a condition of alert it gives this error.

Comment: Hello everyone, I was not able to find any solution for this but I was able to stop this warning by deleting my indices so that it freed up space in my device, then I used **reboot** command to reboot my centos 8 machine and now my elastalert is working as it should

Comment: This error occurs when the rule is called but the rule is currently running. It could be caused by a huge index, which deletion of your indexes would resolve. Alternatively it could be an expensive aggregation (eg. cardinality over metric aggregation).